# Jquery class name start selector not working in two different situations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Code is working  for first 3 but not  for last 3. What can  be possible reasons?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("section[class^='steps-']").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--hiding-->     

    <section class="steps-1">
     <h1>Hidden</h1>
    </section>
    <section class="steps-2">
     <h1>hidden</h1>
    </section>

<!--not hiding-->

    <section class="another-class steps-3">
     <h1>not hiding</h1>
    </section>
    <section class="another-class steps-4">
     <h1>not hiding</h1>
    </section>
```

Comment: Your attribute selector looks like its a "starts with" rather than a "contains", see https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Answer (score 2):

The reason it those two elements also contain another class.
In this case [attribute-contains-selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector that will check if a value contains a given substring.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("section[class*='steps-']").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="steps-1">
  <h1>Hidden</h1>
</section>
<section class="steps-2">
  <h1>hidden</h1>
</section>
<section class="another-class steps-3">
  <h1>not hiding</h1>
</section>
<section class="another-class  steps-4">
  <h1>not hiding</h1>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

classes that starts with `steps-`

```
$("section[class^='steps-']").hide();
```

classes that contain `steps-`

```
$("section[class*='steps-']").hide();
```

classes that contain `steps-` but not start with `steps-`

```
$("section[class*=' steps-']").hide();//observe the space
```

and you need contains:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("section[class*='steps-']").hide();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="steps-1">
    <h1>Hidden</h1>
</section>
<section class="steps-2">
    <h1>hidden</h1>
</section>
<section class="another-class steps-3">
    <h1>not hiding</h1>
</section>
<section class="another-class  steps-4">
    <h1>not hiding</h1>
</section>
```

Comment: how it is exactly working. I think it not checks class separately. I mean if I put class to first then it works fine in same code.

Comment: I have explained it. `class^='steps-'` is a starting with class `steps-` selector. whereas `class*='steps-'` selects all elements which contain class `steps`, it being at first or at last. So you must go with `class*='steps'` instead of `class^='steps'`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `*`, it will check the contains query in the class names string,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("section[class*='steps-']").hide();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="steps-1">
    <h1>Hidden</h1>
</section>
<section class="steps-2">
    <h1>hidden</h1>
</section>
<section class="steps-3 another-class">
    <h1>not hiding</h1>
</section>
<section class="another-class  steps-4">
    <h1>not hiding</h1>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("section[class^='steps-']").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--hiding-->     

    <section class="steps-1">
     <h1>Hidden</h1>
    </section>
    <section class="steps-2">
     <h1>hidden</h1>
    </section>

<!--not hiding-->

    <section class="steps-3 another-class">
     <h1>not hiding</h1>
    </section>
    <section class="steps-4 another-class">
     <h1>not hiding</h1>
    </section>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. The question asks for possible reasons, not working code!